# When to use GEE vs. GLMM

Tags: glmm, generalized-estimating-equations

I'm trying to decide whether I should use GLMM or GEE for my analysis.

My study is repeat cross-sectional using longitudinal data (with 3 timepoints). I have a binary outcome and both continuous and categorical predictors. Data is hierarchal with hospitals as clusters.

So far, I know that:

- GEE: population averages, MCAR, Fixed effects
- GLMM: individual averages, MCAR or MAR, random and fixed effects

I understand that the Research question is a key indicator of which analytic approach to use. However, I am unable to find examples of how a research question should be phrased to distinguish if its focus is on the subject level or population level.

Any help/examples would be appreciated in terms of application.

Thank you!